# Changes to array are not being made/kept

Tags: c++, arrays

Part of a homework assignment was to write a quick sort in c++ in 'functional style'.  I've got the code down for the most part, but the only problem I am having is that the changes to the array are not staying.  Here is my code, I know it may not completely look like functional programming but my teacher said it was fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

void swap(int* x, int* y);
int partition(int arr[], int low, int high, int cursor);
void quickSort(int A[], int start, int end);

int main(){
    int list[20] = {20, 5, 12, 11, 1, 6, 18, 7, 2, 3, 14, 19, 10, 4, 13, 8, 15, 9, 17, 16};
    quickSort(list,0,19);
    for(int count =0; count<20; count++){
        std::cout<< list[count] << " ";
    }

};

void swap(int* x, int* y){
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
};

int partition(int arr[], int low, int high, int cursor){
    if(low == high){
        swap(&arr[cursor+1], &arr[high]);
        return cursor+1;
    }else if(arr[low] <= arr[high]){
        swap(&arr[cursor+1], &arr[low]);
        return partition(arr, low+1, high, cursor+1);
    }else if(arr[low] > arr[high] && low != high){
            return partition(arr, low+1, high, cursor);
    }
};

void quickSort(int A[], int start, int end){
    if(start < end){
        int p = partition(A, start, end, start-1);
        quickSort(A, start, p-1);
        quickSort(A, p+1, end);
    }
};
```

Comment: `partition()` returns nothing when `low != high && arr[low] > arr[high]`. Fix it first.

Comment: I was using the code from here as a reference, it didn't seem to use that case: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-quick-sort/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to timrau who pointed out the missing conditional, my problem was fixed.  A foolish rookie mistake, which I will kick myself for later.  Thanks.  On the off chance that someone else might have problem like this, the code I added to fix the issue was this:

```
else if(arr[low] > arr[high] && low != high){
    return partition(arr, low+1, high, cursor);
}
```